# Why the slope of a line is change in y divided by change in x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why the slope of a line isn't  the change in x divided by the change in y?

Comment: The other question asks why we use $\delta y/\delta x$ rather than the angle that is the arctangent of this fraction. So, related, but not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is an equally valid way to represent slope, however it is *customary* to treat the $x$ as an independent variable, and $y$ as a function of $x$.

With that in mind, drawing a line in the $xy$-plane will give you an equation of the form:

$$y(x) = mx + b$$

Using the test points $(x_1, y_1), (x_2,y_2)$:

$$y_1 = mx_1 + b \\ y_2 = mx_2 + b$$
Subtracting the first from the second,
$$y_2 - y_1 = m(x_2 - x_1) \\ \implies m = \frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1}$$

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it's to make the definition consistent with the normal English meaning of the word "slope". When we say that a landscape  has "no slope" we mean that the ground is flat. Assuming that $y$ measures vertical height, this means that there is no change in $y$. When we say a "large slope" or a "steep slope", we mean a large change in height, specifically a large change in $y$ over a small horizontal distance.

People understand this sort of language even if they don't know the mathematical definition of "slope". It would be very confusing if the mathematical definition were inconsistent with everyday speech.